# Trouble rotating coordinates about origin

Tags: matlab, rotation, coordinates

I'm having some difficulty getting a simple script to work. The goal is to rotate an array of points about the origin using some angle. However, the code I'm using seems not to maintain the magnitude of the vector.

Im using a array where the first column is x coordinate and the second is y coordinate:

```
for ii=1:1000
    angleRads=rand()*2*pi;
    randRotPoints(ii,1)=1*cos(angleRads)-0*sin(angleRads);
    randRotPoints(ii,2)=0*cos(angleRads)+1*sin(angleRads);
end
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths1=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);

for ii=1:1000
    angleRads=rand()*2*pi;
    randRotPoints(ii,1)=randRotPoints(ii,1)*cos(angleRads)-randRotPoints(ii,2)*sin(angleRads);
    randRotPoints(ii,2)=randRotPoints(ii,2)*cos(angleRads)+randRotPoints(ii,1)*sin(angleRads);
end
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths2=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);
```

After the first loop, there is a coordinates of magnitude of 1 and random orientation. This is confirmed via the scatter plot and the lengths1 array is all 1s.

[image]

However, the second loop that attempts to rotate those coordinates by a second random angle results in seemingly randomly located coordinates (based on the scatter plot), and the lengths are no longer all 1.

[image]

Please help me figure out where I've gone wrong with this rotation code. I know that this isn't the most efficient code in terms of performance or number of lines, if you want to provide a better way to do it in terms of efficiency that is fine, but please also state what would be needed to fix the code in its current format as well.

Thanks.

Comment: See my updated solution for an improvement of the algorithm:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second loop you have

```
randRotPoints(ii,1)=randRotPoints(ii,1)*cos(angleRads)-randRotPoints(ii,2)*sin(angleRads);

randRotPoints(ii,2)=randRotPoints(ii,2)*cos(angleRads)+randRotPoints(ii,1)*sin(angleRads);
```

i.e. you use the overwritten (rotated) `x` coordinate when computing the `y`. Try saving the `randRotPoints(ii,:)` vector before rotating it, and using the saved value on the right hand side.

As for making it more efficient:

### The more *readable* solution

You can make the code much more readable by explicitly defining the rotation matrix for each point

```
for ii=1:1000
    angleRads=rand()*2*pi;
    rotmat=[cos(angleRads) -sin(angleRads); sin(angleRads) cos(angleRads)];
    randRotPoints(ii,:)=rotmat*[1; 0];
    %note that this is equivalent to
    %randRotPoints(ii,:)=[cos(angleRads); sin(angleRads)];
end
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths1=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);

for ii=1:1000
    angleRads=rand()*2*pi;
    rotmat=[cos(angleRads) -sin(angleRads); sin(angleRads) cos(angleRads)];
    randRotPoints(ii,:)=rotmat*(randRotPoints(ii,:).');
end
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths2=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);
```

In order to spare some code-duplication you could also define a `rotmatfun=@(angleRads) [cos(angleRads) -sin(angleRads); sin(angleRads) cos(angleRads);` function, then you can just say `rotmat=rotmatfun(angleRads);` in the loops.

### The more *efficient* solution

You can do away with your loops entirely by making use of the vectorized notation:

```
N=1000; %number of points

angleRads=rand(N,1)*2*pi;
randRotPoints=[1*cos(angleRads)-0*sin(angleRads), ...
               0*cos(angleRads)+1*sin(angleRads)]; %matrix of size [N,2]
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths1=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);

angleRads=rand(N,1)*2*pi;
randRotPoints=[randRotPoints(:,1).*cos(angleRads)-randRotPoints(:,2).*sin(angleRads), ...
               randRotPoints(:,2).*cos(angleRads)+randRotPoints(:,1).*sin(angleRads)];
figure;
scatter(randRotPoints(:,1),randRotPoints(:,2));
lengths2=sqrt(randRotPoints(:,1).^2+randRotPoints(:,2).^2);
```